# update SQL WHERE BOOKNO = BOOK number in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table Books which has its bookauthorID in another table that is Author

```
BOOK

ID    BOOK NAME   AUTHORID
 0      A           NULL
 1      B           NULL
 2      C           NULL

AUTHOR

 BOOKID     AUTHORID

 0            123
 1            1234
 2            12345
```

Now I have to fill up AuthorID column in Book table from Author table where BOOK.ID = AUTHOR.BOOKID as the BOOK.AUTHORID column was added later in the table

So far

I have this

```
WITH ALLBOOKSANDAUTHORIDS AS
(
SELECT * FROM BOOK INNER JOIN AUTHOR on BOOK.ID = AUTHOR.BOOKID
)
```

I now have a table telling each book and its author ID

but how can I update the BOOK.AUTHORID with correct values, getting values from Author table and putting them in book ?

It is like a for loop where go to each row in Book table and check which ID matches in the Author table, then get the AUTHORID and update it in book table.

Please tell how to write the SQL ?

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: Thanks ALL, I will give it a try and will tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `update`/`join`:

```
update b
    set b.authorid = a.authorid
    from book b join
         author a
         on b.id = a.bookid
    where b.authorid is null;
```

Comment: Genuis man! I am marking this as answer as you have added NULL check which other answers have not, it is necessary to make sure the performce is fast when there is a large table. THANKS A LOT!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply join those table and do update.

```
update book b join author a on (a.bookid=b.id)
    set b.AUTHORID=a.AUTHORID
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all ID can not be ***Zero***, And ans to your question is may be simaple Update statement with join

```
Update B
SET  B.AUTHORID=A.AUTHORID
FROM Book B
INNER JOIN  AUTHOR A ON A.BOOKID = B.ID
```

Comment: You are missing the `=` symbol on your join.

Comment: @Igor Updated Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE BOOK
SET AUTHORID = AUTHOR.AUTHORID
FROM BOOK INNER JOIN AUTHOR ON BOOK.ID = AUTHOR.BOOKID
```

Comment: This is also great answer as all other, just missing NULL check otherwise all answers are similar and super

Comment: @Aiden - the `null` check only allows you to run a faster update if some of the records in `BOOK` already have a value for `AuthorId`. If it's a new column (*as you stated in the question*) or none of the records have an `AuthorId` value then the check on NULL does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this I think

Update b
Set b.AUTHORID = ( Select top 1 a.AUTHORID From AUTHOR a 
where b.ID =  a.BOOKID)